# What are the stances of different political parties about Gentrification?

Tags: economy, environmental-policy, society, industrial-policy

One of the thing I notice all the time; is that every political parties bring policies or actions that create massive planned or unplanned [urbanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbanization) ([people often don't want that](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2018/feb/12/india-villagers-rebel-urbanisation-gujarat)). As a result, the traditional way of living becomes extremely difficult and unsupported, the society breaks apart, former prosperous farmer or cottage artisan require to leave their work and move into to cities either as daily wage workers or somehow fit as a cog into industrialization or modern job market.

> [image: chaplin]
> Pic: Charles Chaplin acts as a cog in a machine, alludes human life being used as a cog in industrial process. In a conventional local market, the sellers and customers build a more humanitarian connection, whereas in shopping malls and online delivery networks, the delivery persons often work like a cog in a machine. There are no connection with people, and they can be fired from job on a click of a button of the customers or the employers.

Also changes in job market cause people to leave their home and society, in order to do a 24x7 job in a distant city (such as for a technology company) as a result own land, farm, pond or other properties lose its security. The down-to-earth social connectivity ([social capital?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_capital)) completely disrupted.

> [image: Disruption of traditional agriculture through industrialization]
> image: Disruption of traditional agriculture through industrialization, [source](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2018/feb/12/india-villagers-rebel-urbanisation-gujarat) by Rupak de Chowdhuri/Reuters, Fair use.

I don't konow what is a proper term for this, but some people are telling this as an example of [Gentrification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentrification) (Such as [National Geographic](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/gentrification/)); which can have some positive impact, but I personally feel this as mostly a negative impact on people, ease of life, as well cultural heritage.

I need to know about whether the political parties (Western left or right parties or the other parties in other countries) recognize this problem or not, and whether include them in their ideologies/agenda. If they include this, then whether they see this as positive and negative thing.

Up to my personal observation; the parties are inconsistent about this issue, such as:

1. The right wing parties say a lot about heritage, cultural tradition, and the "good old days", but at the same time they usually support heavy industrialization and commercialization that actually destroy or economically commoditify the heritage and cultural traditions.
2. The left wing and centre-left parties say a lot about supporting local people, farmers, cottage industries etc; but they bring more globalization, discourage conventional family structures, and sometimes take part in massive industrialization and destruction of nature. For example, in my locale, the centre-left to centre-right parties prefer a mass destruction of trees and in name of beautification of roads, they often concrete over exposed soil.

Now what are the local and global stances on this problem?

Comment: Different political parties where? There's probably thousands of political parties on the globe.

Comment: I am not sure if "gentrification" is the right word, as it usually applys to poo *urban* populations being forced to move into the city. The problem you describe seems to be about poor *rural* populations being forced to move out of the city.

Comment: @xyldke  I borrowed the word from National geographic, as well I already wrote in the question I am not sure if I am using the right terminology.

Comment: You point this as a negative, but on average moving from rural manual agriculture to urban life comes with a major increase in income and hence a significant increase in standard of living. Politicial parties on either side generally approve of that.

Comment: @xyldke - as I understand it, in modern US usage, the term *gentrification* refers to demographic shift where a richer population displaces a poorer one, with rising cost of living typically the direct cause. NYC in the 1990s is a classic example. Often the displaced working class population has to move further from the urban centers. This is in contrast to *urbanization*, which is increase in population density - which doesn't by itself imply any group has to leave.

Comment: @xyldke then it is applicable for india too. The richer communities ingress towards other localities. They destroy nature through real estate, and also destroy many heritage building and local communities.

Comment: Your question contains an all-consuming way of arguing that deserves an answer in kind: Cities have been a feature of civilization for 7000 years. Division of labor between city and country became a major feature of society 800 years ago. Industrialization has been around for almost 300 years. Every party that tries to politically oppose this wants to bereave humanity from their source of living, and to destroy its cultural heritage, not protect it.

Comment: @ccprog You can make that an answer. There can be opposing answer.

Comment: It's not an answer, it is the reason why I voted to close the question as "needs more focus".

Comment: @ccprog May you suggest, which part is not focused? and what more focus can be added?

Comment: @ccprog I don't know if any political parties oppose this, but if this is not regulated it will destroy humanity. Too much of anything is bad.

Comment: @Citizen and Society - it's recognized, and depending on where you are, policies to encourage or require or subsidize affordable housing exist. And ofc there is disagreement about it, since at its root is a redistributive policy. FWIW I think the Q is a good one.

Comment: This is likely too broad to answer.  You could write a book on how, for example, European farm policy and product labeling requirements support niche industries and practices (i.e. champagne the drink can only be made from grapes grown in the Champagne region of France) and how different political parties have formulated that policy over time.

Comment: @JustinCave is it impossible to shorten down to point wise examples?

Comment: The correct term is **[urbanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbanization)**: "the population shift from rural to urban areas, the corresponding decrease in the proportion of people living in rural areas, and the ways in which societies adapt to this change." (Also industrialization as in the Chaplin film is a different thing again.)

Comment: @oh I streesed on the change of social structure

Comment: This question might be a bit too broad because it's asking about the whole world and there are thousands of parties. Also what is the stance is very broad. Everything from we should do something specific to it to it will sort out by itself falls under that. More focus and limit yourself on the most important things, ask the rest in subsequent questions, would be good, I think.

Comment: Just asking about the stance of a single party is already a broad question, beyond that is asking for a book to be written.

Answer (score 3):

In [europe](/questions/tagged/europe), the term **gentrification** is usually applied to a situation where a *poor* city district attracts *rich* immigrants, who then drive up rents and other prices and thus drive out the original inhabitants.

Some people and some parties *like* gentrification because they see how the average wealth in the city district (and probably in the entire city) goes up. Those wealthy people pay more taxes, they spend money on goods and services, and so on. The economy turns.

Some people and some parties *oppose* gentrification because poorer and more vulnerable members of society are driven to the margins. Society wants bakers, and barbers, and cops in the wealthy districts, so shouldn't they be able to afford living there? They see problems for society if there is too much segregation.

*In Germany, the Left are against gentrification, the Greens and the Social Democrats also but less vocally, the Liberal Democrats are for it, the Conservatives are for it but less vocally, and the far right has a muddled position.*

The term **social capital** refers to non-monetary factors which give people social regard and influence. For instance, the clergy is often upper middle class when it comes to wealth (a catholic priest in Germany averages 1.5 times median income), but they are higher than that in social regard. When they speak up in city hall, they are listened to.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the US.

Before talking about the associated politics, lets start with Urbanization vs Gentrification.

*Urbanization* refers to increase in population density. Widespread pattern of new and larger buildings in the same place. On the one hand it offers economic efficiency (more physical business linkages within the same travel time, more available specialists of all kinds), on the other hand it can bring social ills when unplanned or badly planned. **Potentially**: traffic, pollution, culture of anonymity, alienation, crime, and sundry human vices.

*Gentrification* refers to demographic shift, where a richer population displaces a poorer one. Rising cost of living usually the direct mechanism. NYC in the 1990s is a classic example. Typically, working class population continues to work in the same place, but now has to live further from the urban center, and travel longer to work.

Unlike *urbanization*, the pattern of *gentrification* by definition implies that a group of people is being pushed out.

Now to the causes and politics.

There can be an element of industrialization or de-industrialization, but it's not required.

Urbanization can be somewhat spontaneous, though even then there is at least a formal layer of policy in the form of zoning laws. It can also be planned at a grand level, such as in China. Or anything between. When there isn't a large scale policy, and zoning changes incrementally and passively (accomodating demand), the process is dramatically accelerated in times of low interest rates. Since the consolidation of property ownership and then new construction, both involve more and riskier financing, than the exchange of existing properties. That is also a mechanism of policy link.

Gentrification is a little more predictable, I believe. Painting in broad strokes, the two key mechanisms for it are (1) desire of property owners to maximize their property value, and (2) in the US, the fact of primary and secondary school funding being tied to local property taxes, and their budgeting being also decided locally. Once again municipal politics dominates the picture

There's an old adadge (again in the US), that local politics is all about real estate, which is to say the debates are over land use, and the strongest voices are property owners, especially large property owners. Whatever other opinions property owners will have, they'll want their property values maximized.

Intimately related to this, in the US, is school zoning. Since parents will want the best for their kids, but not more than they can pay, this tends to reinforce and encourage self-sorting by wealth/income, at the granularity of the school-zone. Lets say you're going to build luxury housing. If you build it in a "good", i.e. already wealthy, school zone, then families with children will pay a premium for it. In fact any kind of housing, will have a higher bid in an already wealthy school zone.

Local policy can and sometimes does reinforce this even further. For example, by having lower limits on lot size, choosing not to invest in transport, or no-retail zoning. Each of which effectively exclude low income properties. It should be noted that these apply to suburban areas.

Sometimes, there is a counter trend, to encourage mixed-income development. The key is *affordable housing*, either encouraged or required or subsidized. But that takes a much more deliberate policy drive, and tends to face resistance. In today's US this is typically associated with the progressive flavor of Democratic party - but you'll also find large property owners who are Democrats opposing it on grounds of pure self interest. Republicans on the whole are more consistently *economic-liberal* (*libertarian* in US lingo), and oppose redistributive policy.

I don't think there is systematic opposition to *urbanization* at all - though there may well be resentment in parts of the country.

As a final, anecdotal data point: I live in a university town about 250 miles inland from the East Coast urban strip.

- Progressive Democrat municipality (due to the university influence)
- Favors urbanization, via zoning, on the grounds that it makes it more cost-effective to deliver social services
- Favors affordable housing, via zoning and subsidy of thousands of housing units.
- Despite this, experiencing undeniable gentrification. From the market action via the effects I described earlier.